# How do I link and compile Raylib on windows?

Tags: c, raylib

I have installed the raylib migw from the official source. The installation directory is `C:\raylib\raylib`. I have written the sample program from the website as follows.

```
#include "raylib.h"

int main(void){
    const int screenWidth = 800;
    const int screenHeight = 600;

    InitWindow(screenWidth, screenHeight, "raylib basic window test");

    SetTargetFPS(60);

    while(!WindowShouldClose()){
        BeginDrawing();
        ClearBackground(RAYWHITE);
        DrawText("Congrats! You created your first window!", 190, 200, 20, LIGHTGRAY);

        EndDrawing();
    }

    CloseWindow();

    return 0;
}
```

I have compiled it using `gcc main.c -I C:\raylib\raylib\src` and when I do this, I'm getting the following error

```
C:\Users\jaych\AppData\Local\Temp\ccOHQPti.o:main.c:(.text+0x37): undefined reference to `InitWindow'
C:\Users\jaych\AppData\Local\Temp\ccOHQPti.o:main.c:(.text+0x43): undefined reference to `SetTargetFPS'
C:\Users\jaych\AppData\Local\Temp\ccOHQPti.o:main.c:(.text+0x48): undefined reference to `WindowShouldClose'
C:\Users\jaych\AppData\Local\Temp\ccOHQPti.o:main.c:(.text+0x58): undefined reference to `BeginDrawing'
C:\Users\jaych\AppData\Local\Temp\ccOHQPti.o:main.c:(.text+0x86): undefined reference to `ClearBackground'
C:\Users\jaych\AppData\Local\Temp\ccOHQPti.o:main.c:(.text+0xce): undefined reference to `DrawText'
C:\Users\jaych\AppData\Local\Temp\ccOHQPti.o:main.c:(.text+0xd3): undefined reference to `EndDrawing'
C:\Users\jaych\AppData\Local\Temp\ccOHQPti.o:main.c:(.text+0xdd): undefined reference to `CloseWindow'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: There's no makefile?

Comment: @stark I don't know how to compile this, so I did not create a makefile. And there is no makefile available on the GitHub wiki too.

Comment: Add a link to the source to your post.

Comment: https://github.com/raysan5/raylib/wiki/Working-on-Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `libraylib.a` file into `lib` folder, then run the following command

`gcc main.c -o main -O1 -Wall -std=c99 -Wno-missing-braces -L ./lib/ -lraylib -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -lwinmm`

Comment: PSA: Do not use `raylib.lib`; I tried it and it gave me all these weird undefined reference errors

Comment: @iwrestledthebeartwice I used your command to compile the code but got the following error: `fatal error: raylib.h: No such file or directory` Any idea how to fix this? I do have a raylib installed in C:\raylib\raylib.